# finding the parent document id based on the sub document _id of array field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Hyy , I have a collection where comments related to the blog are  stored in multiple document as shown below.

```
 [
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("565f0f5d77f0c7bd11bbadd8"),
    "blog_id" : ObjectId("56587befdb7224110f007233"),
    "comments" : [
        {
            "user_id" : ObjectId("562fa014888806820e21e0df"),
            "user_full_name" : "Niroj Paudel",
            "comment" : "pradip is bhole baba",
            "_id" : ObjectId("565f0f5d77f0c7bd11bbadd9"),
            "dt" : ISODate("2015-12-02T15:33:49.578Z")
        },
        {
            "user_id" : ObjectId("562fa014888806820e21e0df"),
            "user_full_name" : "Niroj Paudel",
            "comment" : "honkog pokhara... he he ha ha",
            "_id" : ObjectId("565f1034fd07cbfc1129db0b"),
            "dt" : ISODate("2015-12-02T15:37:24.581Z")
        }
    ],
    "record_count" : 2,
    "__v" : 0
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("565efa37635f09900d21a339"),
    "blog_id" : ObjectId("56587befdb7224110f007233"),
    "comments" : [
        {
            "user_id" : ObjectId("562fa014888806820e21e0df"),
            "user_full_name" : "Niroj Paudel",
            "comment" : "wat a nice car wow",
            "_id" : ObjectId("565efa37635f09900d21a33a"),
            "dt" : ISODate("2015-12-02T14:03:35.289Z")
        },
        {
            "user_id" : ObjectId("562fa014888806820e21e0df"),
            "user_full_name" : "Niroj Paudel",
            "comment" : "love is life budikhola ma dives",
            "_id" : ObjectId("565efa76635f09900d21a33b"),
            "dt" : ISODate("2015-12-02T14:04:38.661Z")
        },
        {
            "user_id" : ObjectId("562fa014888806820e21e0df"),
            "user_full_name" : "Niroj Paudel",
            "comment" : "bholi ajaya ko bihe",
            "_id" : ObjectId("565efaa0635f09900d21a33c"),
            "dt" : ISODate("2015-12-02T14:05:20.847Z")
        },
        {
            "user_id" : ObjectId("562fa014888806820e21e0df"),
            "user_full_name" : "Niroj Paudel",
            "comment" : "manish is nice",
            "_id" : ObjectId("565efb17635f09900d21a33d"),
            "dt" : ISODate("2015-12-02T14:07:19.704Z")
        },
        {
            "user_id" : ObjectId("562fa014888806820e21e0df"),
            "user_full_name" : "Niroj Paudel",
            "comment" : "niroj is cool",
            "_id" : ObjectId("565efd53c22dddc80e8f461c"),
            "dt" : ISODate("2015-12-02T14:16:51.730Z")
        },
        {
            "user_id" : ObjectId("562fa014888806820e21e0df"),
            "user_full_name" : "Niroj Paudel",
            "comment" : "ramesh is cool",
            "_id" : ObjectId("565f0d376d82e24c11f6c0d1"),
            "dt" : ISODate("2015-12-02T15:24:39.010Z")
        }
    ],
    "record_count" : 6,
    "__v" : 0
}
]
```

Suppose user wants to update his comment; for this I would have the comments _id now my problem is that how can I detect in which document the comment exist based of the comment _id value of comments array field.

suppose I have a comment "_id" : "565f0f5d77f0c7bd11bbadd9"  (first element of first document)
then the result should give the parent document _id:"565f0f5d77f0c7bd11bbadd8" (first document id)

How can I do this..

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

if possible, then please update your schema.
Suppose you have collection of Blog. Then your code will be :

```
Blog.find({'comments._id' : '565f0f5d77f0c7bd11bbadd9'}).exec(function(err,blog){
    if(!err && blog){
        console.log("Blog id :"+blog._id);
    }
    else{
        console.log("Dont get your blog");
    }
});
```

Comment: This query works only when comments are in single documents.... Actually this is a dummy problem that resemble my original problem.....

Answer (score 0):

if your comments are directly stored on the blog document you could go with an aggregate method to collect the comment across all documents. **note that this seems to work when you don't have any object references to be populated.**

asuming all documents are based on a blog Schema and that you wish to recieve the id of the comment:

```
Blog.aggregate(
[{'$match':{'comments':{'$elemMatch:{'_id':'565f0f5d77f0c7bd11bbadd9'}}}},

{'$project':{comments:'$_id', user_id:1}},
{'$unwind':'$comments'}
{'$group':{_id:'$comments'}}
]).exec(function(err, results){
    if(results){
       console.log(results);
    }
});
```

I hope this is somewhat what you're looking for, you might find the following read usefull
[elementMatch](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) and [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) from the mongoDB docs.

cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The site recommended this old question to me as being `Related` to another I was looking at. Looks like a sufficient answer wasn't ever given, so I'll provide it for any future readers.

The requested behavior here is very straightforward to achieve with a basic `find()` query:

```
db.collection.find(
  { "comments._id": ObjectId("565f0f5d77f0c7bd11bbadd9") },
  { _id: 1 }
)
```

Here we are filtering the documents based on the values of the `_id` fields embedded in the `comments` array. Then for the matching document(s) we are applying a projection to just retrieve the `_id` field of the "parent document" (e.g. the document that was matched). If the `_id`s for the `comments` are unique then there will only ever be a maximum of a single matching document. Sample [playground demonstration is here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Uvwo0GrnlS5).

A more complicated aggregation would have only been necessary here if the intent was to always provide the `_id` value of the *first* document associated with a given `blog_id` but that does *not* appear to be the case here.